# How to zscan over lua table results in script

Tags: redis, lua

I am writing a Lua script to execute in redis. I am working with Sorted Sets that look like this:

`Member: 96954_1_1557705600
Score: 1557705600`

The score is a unix epoch time stamp.

I would like to first get the results that are between two time stamps, then filter those based of a glob pattern in the member. Something like `MATCH *_1_*`.

My script looks like this, but it's failing when I try and pass the Lua table to zscan:

`local start_date = KEYS[1]
local end_date = KEYS[2]
local limited_by_date =  redis.call('zrangebyscore','rooms', start_date, end_date)
return redis.call('zscan', unpack(limited_by_date), 'match *_1_*')`

`limited_by_date` correct contains the values I expect, but how can I search through them with zscan now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get `limited_by_date`, you can iterate the array yourself, and output items that match the pattern.

```
local result = {}
for i, mem in ipairs(limited_by_date) do
    if string.match(mem, ".+_1_.+") then result[#result + 1] = mem end
end

return result
```

There's no need to use the `ZSCAN` command. In fact, if you use `ZSCAN`, you have to intersect `ZSCAN` result and `ZRANGEBYSCORE` result to get the final answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Performance is biggest concern. `limited_by_date` could be have a length > 1K. Do you think it would be more performant to iterate the array, or use the `zinterstore` method to find the intersect? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @calbear47 If the set is too large, neither solution is good. It might take a long time to iterate the array, or `ZSCAN` the set. Instead, you should save data in different set for different patterns. For instance, save items that match pattern `*_1_*` to a set, and save items that match pattern `*_2_*` to another set. Then you only need to call `ZRANGEBYSCORE` to get the result.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?! Thanks, I appreciate your help. I think that's what I'm ultimately going to do. But I'm glad I figured out how scripting works.